# Data not completely received on the receiver side when sleep is introduced on the receiver side

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am using a file transfer application using tcp sockets. In normal scenario,when i try to send a file using the application the complete file is received, but when i put a sleep of 40 ms in between every packets received i am receiving only part of the file. I am also closing the socket immediately after the complete file is sent out to the output stream. What could be the possible reason why i am not receiving the complete file?. Below is the code for the sender side and receiver side. Thanks in advance.

```
/////////////////////////Sender Side////////////////////////////

bytesLeft = fileSize;
while(bytesLeft > 0) 
{
    try 
    {
        bytesRead = fileInpStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
        outStream.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        try 
        {
             fileInpStream.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            Log.i(LOGC, "Error " + e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
            disconnect();
            return;
        }
    }
    bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
    if (bytesLeft < 1) 
    {
      try 
      {
        fileInpStream.close();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
//Closing the socket immediately after all the data are sent to out stream.
try 
{
    socket.close();
} 
catch (StcException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


/////////////////Receiver Side//////////////////////////

bytesLeft = filesize;
while (bytesLeft > 0) 
{
    try 
    {
      if (bytesLeft < BUFFERSIZE)
        readAmount = (int) bytesLeft;
      bytesRead = inpstream.read(buf, 0, readAmount);
      if (bytesRead < 1) 
      {
        fileoutputstream.close();
      }
      fileoutputstream.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 0,bytesRead));
      bytesLeft -= bytesRead;

      //Including a sleep of 40 ms or more doesnt completely receive the data.
      //try{ sleep(40) } catch(Exception e){ }

      if (bytesLeft == 0) 
      {
        fileoutputstream.close();
      }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      try 
      {
        fileoutputstream.close();
      } 
      catch (IOException e1) 
      {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sleep in the first place. Leave it out. It is just literally a waste of time. Your code is several times as complex as it needs to be, and probably masking a few lurking bugs. This:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
```

is sufficient, at both ends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code works perfectly without the sleep. I am implementing this sleep to reproduce the error and see what goes wrong?. The reason why i am using sleep is there are so many post processing that happens after a file is received which takes some time. Imagine if you are sending hundred empty files for each file you receive there will be a delay on the receiver side as a part of the post processing. I close the socket on the sender without closing the stream, but i do make a shutdown input/output before closing will that make any difference?.

Comment: It's still pointless where you have it. Just slowing down the download part doesn't accurately reproduce a postprocessing delay. Move the sleep to after you've received the file, so that you're testing something real. You should close the output stream, not the socket, and you don't need any shutdowns.

Comment: Thanks EJP. I closed the output stream and it worked but my receiver side is not receiving read() = -1 even after closing the socket on the sender side. Sender is sending the bytes and closing the socket immediately after all bytes are sent out, while on the receiver side as there is a delay it completes receiving the bytes 20 seconds later but i am not receiving -1. I also debugged to see what value is received but the control just vanished when i did inputstream.read(buffer) no exceptions are caught. I also read about the Close_wait state of the tcp is that something related to that. Thanks.